# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'X' when running the application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, dllimport, project-reference

I am developing an extension for Autodesk Vault but recently I got the following error when I try to set the references of the programm DLLs to `Copy Local = false`:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'X' or one of its dependencies

Oddly enough it works when I set the attribute `Copy Local` to `true` for some reason.

FYI: The DLLs are being referenced from the Installation Folder of the Vault application so it should work just fine. I have also checked if they are actually there (just in case) and yes they exist.

What I have tried to fix this:

1. Removing the references and adding them again
2. Compiling the project with x86 architecture
3. Cleaning and rebuilding the application

Unfortunately the Referencing still only works if I set the `Copylocal` attribute to `true`, otherwise it throws me the IO Exception. **The Error occurs on runtime of the program.**

Is there any way to fix this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The dlls need to be in the same folder as the net executables.  CopyTo put the dll into the bin folder of the project.  If you want the dlls in another location than you have to include the path in the c# code.

Comment: But the DLLs don't need to be in the same folder. It is just that the referencing seems to be broken. The DLLs are going to exist in the main Programs folder - always.

My program just has to load those references from the other program because otherwise we'd have multiple copies of the very same DLL in different extensions, which creates an insane amount of bloat.

Comment: Then you may need to edit with notepad the csproj files to get the path names correct.  The csproj all ways puts c:\......... and sometimes it is better to organize using relative folders.   So I have changed the absolute path names in the csproj file to relative paths.

Comment: You can also register the dlls than they will be in one place See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool?force_isolation=true